# Multiple Conditional Formatting Variables in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

Here's what I've got at the moment:

```
'Highlight If N=19 & R=OR
Range("G4:R1000").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$N4=19"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = True
```

I am trying to highlight a few cells based on multiple criteria. If N=19 and if R=OR.  I can only get the N=19 portion to work.

Comment: Change it to `Formula1:="=AND($N4=19, $R4=""OR"")"`

Comment: Works perfectly and was able to further modify it to my needs.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the formula adjustment I made in comments above should solve your problem but here is how I clean up recorded Conditional Formatting code.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With .Range("G4:R1000")
        With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND($N4=19, $R4=""OR"")")
            With .Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 255
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            .SetFirstPriority
        End With
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = True
    End With
End With
```

Removing the verbose qualifying code (e.g. `Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count)...`) makes it much more readable.